# Graph does not render properly due to vertices overlap

Tags: mxgraph

Graph is not rendering properly because two vertex has the same co-ordinates hence the length of the edge between this two vertex is zero.Since edge's length is zero the x&y co-ordinates are set as NaN in mxParallelEdgeLayout.prototype.layout function.

How can I ensure vertices not to overlap and stay at least a certain distance from one another.Our application uses mxFastOrganicLayout layout and mxgraph version is 1.8.0.5.

Comment: Can you add a code sample?